# Extjs buffered store loads all new added items

Tags: extjs, grid, store, extjs4.1, buffered

I am trying to use Ext's **(4.1.1)** buffered store/grid combination with data, which I cannot access directly through a rest Api.. or so, but the incoming data is handled by my controller and want just add this data to the buffered grid.

And here comes the problem, when I load 500 items directly to the store, the buffering is working.. Only items which I can see gets rendered, but when I start to `store.add(items)` then they all gets automatically rendered..

So this is my store & grid:

#### Store

```
this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    storeId: 'reportDataStore',
    fields: [
        { name: 'html'}
    ],
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 100,
    autoLoad: true
});
```

#### Grid

```
  {
      xtype: 'gridpanel',
      flex: 1,
      hideHeaders: true,
      store: this.store,
      verticalScroller: {
          rowHeight: 43
      },
      disableSelection: true,
      columns: [
          { header: '', dataIndex: 'html', flex: 1 }
      ]
  }
```

#### Data Controller

```
...
// somewhere in initialization process of the controller, 
// I take the reportDataStore, for later reusing
    this.reportDataStore = Ext.getStore('reportDataStore');
...
onNewData: function(data) {
    this.reportDataStore.add(data)
}
```

So my expectation was, that data will get into the store, but only the visible data will get rendered.. Now it is so, that all new data gets rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to produce a working example with the code you give, but I've got something close... How did you even manage to add records to a buffered store backed by a memory proxy?

You should try to push your new data to the proxy directly, and then reload the store, like so:

```
store.proxy.data.push(data);

grid.view.saveScrollState();

// should probably have been a call to reload(), but then the loading never ends...
store.load({
    callback: function() {
        grid.view.restoreScrollState();
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uvo) that tries to reproduce your setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seams to be what I am looking for, but I have some misunderstanding whats going on with the pageSize ( it works best, when the pageSize is the max of possible items) and the sorting is not working, need to implement it by my self on the `store.proxy.data` array.. Or could you maybe show how to sort on the id (DESC)

Comment: Buffered stores use a pageMap to keep in memory pages of size pageSize (see the relevant part in the [constructor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-constructor)'s code). Unfortunately, the memory proxy is a really light implementation that doesn't support paging (see the [code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/Memory.html#Ext-data-proxy-Memory-method-read)). That's why we need a huge pageSize in the store (greater than the total number of records, or it will break).

Comment: As you have noted, it doesn't support sorting either. I had forgotten that it existed in Ext 4.1, but you should try with a [PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy) instead, which supports both paging and sorting (once again, you should give a look to the code).

Comment: Thank rixo, I did. It looks really promisingly ;) Thank you for the point with PagingMemoryProxy, will take a look at it